# Making batch delete request to Google Cloud Storage via http

Tags: http, google-cloud-storage

I need to be able to delete multiple files at a time from a Google Cloud Storage bucket. I am currently using the PHP client, but iterating over objects when I need to delete 30 or 40 at a time seems terribly slow. Batching is no longer supported in the Google client libraries, but per this page, it seems like I could do it with HTTP requests:

https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/batch

I have a request file in the format (updated Jan31):

```
POST /batch/storage/v1 HTTP/1.1
Host: storage.googleapis.com
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary="====delete_AK-AKMLS_22-14540=="
Authorization: Bearer <MY_AUTH_TOKEN>

--====delete_AK-AKMLS_22-14540==
Content-Type: application/http
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
Content-ID: <1706722780-AK-AKMLS-22-14540-org/011.jpg>

DELETE /storage/v1/b/MY_BUCKET_NAME/o/OBJECT_NAME


--====delete_AK-AKMLS_22-14540==

  . . .
```

(OBJECT_NAME is url-encoded). I am trying to send it to the endpoint I pulled from the documentation. Using curl:

```
curl -X POST -d @MY-FILE-NAME https://storage.googleapis.com/batch/storage/v1/
```

But all I get is this extremely helpful error message:

```
The server encountered a temporary error and could not complete your request.
Please try again in 30 seconds. That’s all we know.
```

This is consistent whenever I try it. I have verified, using the single object delete, that I am using the valid auth token (object name is url-encoded):

```
curl -X DELETE \
  -H "Authorization: Bearer MY_AUTH_TOKEN" \
  "https://storage.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b/MY BUCKET/o/OBJECT_NAME"
```

Comment: The url structure should be something like this 
https://storage.googleapis.com/b/MY_BUCKET_NAME/batch/storage/v1

its possible  that you can have an issue with the token.

```
curl -X POST \
  -H "Authorization: Bearer <YOUR_AUTH_TOKEN>" \
  -H "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"====delete_AK-AKMLS_22-14540==\"" \
  --data-binary "@YOUR_REQUEST_FILE" \
  https://storage.googleapis.com/b/MY_BUCKET_NAME/batch/storage/v1
```

Comment: Also to see the error you can see check the logs of Cloud Storage and Cloud Identity and Access Management (IAM) logs in the Google Cloud Console for more info regarding the error.

Comment: Well, I've tried both url structures, and url-encoding the object name (i.e. "o/AK-AKMLS%2F22-14540%2Forg%2F011.jpg". The original url structure and the url-encoding works for the single delete command, but not for the batch. The auth token worked for the single delete, but not the batch. Arg.

Answer (score 2):

This is a simplified working curl example

```
curl --location --request POST 'https://www.googleapis.com/batch/storage/v1' \
--header 'Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=77777' \
--header 'Authorization: Bearer {token}' \
--data-raw '--77777
Content-Type: application/http
Content-ID: 1

DELETE /storage/v1/b/{bucket name}/o/TEMP%2F1572593856429.jpg
--77777
Content-Type: application/http
Content-ID: 2

DELETE /storage/v1/b/{bucket name}/o/TEMP%2F1572603280427.jpg
--77777
Content-Type: application/http
Content-ID: 3

DELETE /storage/v1/b/{bucket name}/o/TEMP%2F1573650760693.jpg
--77777--'
```