# Error in batch delete to google cloud storage (HTTP request)

Tags: http, post, google-cloud-storage

(Updated to show the latest request and results)

I'm trying to use HTTP requests to send a batch delete request to Google Cloud Storage. Per this document:

```
https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/batch
```

and some experimentation and google-ing, it almost works - all but the last file is deleted.

---

### -- curl executed at the command line --

```
curl --location --request POST 'https://www.googleapis.com/batch/storage/v1' \
--header "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary='=========delete_AK-AKMLS_22-14540===='" \
--header "Authorization: Bearer MY_AUTH_TOKEN" \
--data-raw '--=========delete_AK-AKMLS_22-14540====
Content-Type: application/http
Content-ID: <1707427885-AK-AKMLS-22-14540-org/000.jpg>

DELETE /storage/v1/b/MY-BUCKET-NAME/o/AK-AKMLS%2F22-14540%2Forg%2F000.jpg

--=========delete_AK-AKMLS_22-14540====
Content-Type: application/http
Content-ID: <1707427885-AK-AKMLS-22-14540-org/001.jpg>

DELETE /storage/v1/b/MY-BUCKET-NAME/o/AK-AKMLS%2F22-14540%2Forg%2F001.jpg

--=========delete_AK-AKMLS_22-14540====
Content-Type: application/http
Content-ID: <1707427885-AK-AKMLS-22-14540-org/002.jpg>

DELETE /storage/v1/b/MY-BUCKET-NAME/o/AK-AKMLS%2F22-14540%2Forg%2F002.jpg

--=========delete_AK-AKMLS_22-14540====
Content-Type: application/http
Content-ID: <1707427885-AK-AKMLS-22-14540-org/003.jpg>

DELETE /storage/v1/b/MY-BUCKET-NAME/o/AK-AKMLS%2F22-14540%2Forg%2F003.jpg

--=========delete_AK-AKMLS_22-14540===='
```

In this case, the first 2 objects are deleted, but the 3rd one isn't. If I request 5 files to be deleted, 4 are deleted, but not the 5th. The response I got from Google for the request above:

---

### -- RESPONSE --

```
--batch_V1mVEkG9XhCd0_MIf13rGYRrdVxZ0uO2
Content-Type: application/http
Content-ID: <response-1707427885-AK-AKMLS-22-14540-org/000.jpg>

HTTP/1.1 204 No Content
Content-Type: application/json
Date: Thu, 08 Feb 2024 21:33:13 GMT
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Expires: Mon, 01 Jan 1990 00:00:00 GMT
Content-Length: 0


--batch_V1mVEkG9XhCd0_MIf13rGYRrdVxZ0uO2
Content-Type: application/http
Content-ID: <response-1707427885-AK-AKMLS-22-14540-org/001.jpg>

HTTP/1.1 204 No Content
Content-Type: application/json
Date: Thu, 08 Feb 2024 21:33:13 GMT
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Expires: Mon, 01 Jan 1990 00:00:00 GMT
Content-Length: 0


--batch_V1mVEkG9XhCd0_MIf13rGYRrdVxZ0uO2
Content-Type: application/http
Content-ID: <response-1707427885-AK-AKMLS-22-14540-org/002.jpg>

HTTP/1.1 204 No Content
Content-Type: application/json
Date: Thu, 08 Feb 2024 21:33:13 GMT
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Expires: Mon, 01 Jan 1990 00:00:00 GMT
Content-Length: 0


--batch_V1mVEkG9XhCd0_MIf13rGYRrdVxZ0uO2--
```

Per the Google doc, I expected the responses to be "HTTP/1.1 200 OK", not "204 No Content". And the "Expires" being "01 Jan 1990" is also weird. But the weirdest is that, even though the response for each section is the same, the first two objects are deleted, but the third one isn't.

Comment: When posting HTTP and BODY in your question, do not remove any blank lines. They are important.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Making batch delete request to Google Cloud Storage via http](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77909720/making-batch-delete-request-to-google-cloud-storage-via-http)

Comment: Why do you have empty lines after each DELETE. Blank lines have meaning in the HTTP protocol.

Comment: It was a stab in the dark from the example in the Google doc mentioned. I'll try taking them out...

Comment: Ok, I tried removing the blank lines after each delete, and re-tried. The results were identical - only 3 of the 4 files were deleted, and the responses for each delete that did happen were all "HTTP/1.1 204 No Content", and there is no response for the 4th file. 8-(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a working curl example

```
curl --location --request POST 'https://www.googleapis.com/batch/storage/v1' \
--header 'Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=77777' \
--header 'Authorization: Bearer {token}' \
--data-raw '--77777
Content-Type: application/http
Content-ID: 1

DELETE /storage/v1/b/{bucket name}/o/TEMP%2F1572593856429.jpg
--77777
Content-Type: application/http
Content-ID: 2

DELETE /storage/v1/b/{bucket name}/o/TEMP%2F1572603280427.jpg
--77777
Content-Type: application/http
Content-ID: 3

DELETE /storage/v1/b/{bucket name}/o/TEMP%2F1573650760693.jpg
--77777--'
```

Comment: jkb016 - thanks, that's interesting. I followed this model, and it mostly worked.  For some reason, it always skips the last DELETE command.  I'm also trying to get it to work with a file of commands, and/or the PHP cURL library, but this definitely helps.

Comment: we can only check issue if you share the request body that you are using. Also share the response you get from api.
remove any confidential information from request/response before sharing.

Comment: I have updated my question with the request and response bodies.

Comment: @AndyWallace you need to end last line with -- 
eg : 

`DELETE /storage/v1/b/MY-BUCKET-NAME/o/AK-AKMLS%2F22-14540%2Forg%2F003.jpg

--=========delete_AK-AKMLS_22-14540====--`

optional :  the new line is not needed before ending boundary in this particular case of 'delete' request.

Comment: jkb016 - great catch! Thanks so much, that change fixed that issue. I don't know why I missed that from your example. A few more things to work out, but definite step forward.

Comment: Note to followers:  The only hitch here is that the value returned from the batch request does not match the Google documentation. It does not start with "HTTP/1.1 200 OK", and the content-type headers, it starts with the "--batch_<stuff>" header. And, at least in my case, I didn't get "200 OK" responses for each object deleted, I got "204 No Content" instead. But the objects were deleted.

Comment: Your welcome. delete usually returns 204 for most of Google's apis . You can see this without batch requests also.

Comment: Well, wish they would document that. But at least I got it working!